# Optimizar select option en laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo un select option que me trae 17350 registros.

Controller

```
 $paciente = DB::table('pacientes')
        ->select('id',DB::raw('concat(apellido," ",nombre,"-",dni) as apellido'))
        ->orderBy('apellido', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Vista

```
 <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Paciente:</label>
              <select class="form-control" tabindex="7" name="paciente" aria-label="Default select example">
          <option selected>--Seleccione Paciente--</option>
            @foreach($paciente as $paciente)            
            @if (old('paciente')==$paciente->id)
                    <option value={{$paciente->id}} selected>{{ $paciente->apellido }}</option>
                @else
                    <option value={{$paciente->id}} >{{ $paciente->apellido }}</option>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

El problema está en que los primeros segundos demora en traer los datos. Mostrandome la pantalla negra
y luego si muestra los datos correctos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De que forma podría mejorarlo.
Gracias.-

Comment: Y bajo que contexto necesitas listas 17k registros en un select?, lo digo por que por ahi deberiamos de iniciar

Comment: Es el listado de pacientes registrados y esta pantalla es para asignarles el turno.

Comment: Pero los 17k a la vez? fácilmente un usuario se puede perder en ese mar de datos para encontrar el que busca, para mi lo estás enfocando y aplicando mal, imagina entonces le vas a listar todos cuando la bd crezca a 100000 usuarios?

Comment: No lo veo nada usable, la idea de tu pregunta es que te den una respuesta óptima: por qué mejor no recrear un formulario de búsqueda ya sea por DNI, nombre y/o apellidos y entonces asignarle el turno al resultado encontrado!?!?

Comment: Si @Francisco la idea de la consulta era también esa, Como debería mejorar la forma de busqueda. Con el select option  me va acotando al comenzar escribiendo parte del apellido. Como debería hacer lo que planteas? Gracias.

Comment: @JuanManuelFerrero realmemte no soy conocedor de Laravel para darle una respuesta a base de código, pero al menos en la lógica de la funcionalidad y desde el punto de vista de usabilidad pudiera ayudar

Comment: la verdad es mejor que hagas una consulta al select cada vez que vayas escribiendo, por ejemplo si escribes andr te traiga los andres y asi, con eso vas a filtrar mejor y no se van a llenar todos los registros

Comment: como se haria eso @Nicolas . tenes algun link de ejemplo o como lo buscaria. Gracias

Comment: La verdad seria mejor que lo hicieras asincrono con un delay, esperar 2 seg a que el usuario deje de teclerar y envias la consulta al back end

Comment: URGENTE., buen dia estoy preocupado, todavia no realicé ningun cambio sobre este punto pero ahora noto que al cargar un nuevo paciente no se ve reflejando en el select option, sin embargo si está en la tabla, es como que no se refresca, como fuerzo ese refresco no entiendo.

Comment: Les comento que sacando el concat  de la querie me refresca.. Increible laravel

Answer (score 0):

Hayvarias formas de optimizar una consulta eloquent. Varias de las mejores descritas en este [artículo en inglés](https://laravel-news.com/18-tips-to-optimize-your-laravel-database-queries)

1. Usaría chunk para esa consulta

```
DB::table('pacientes')->chunk(100, function ($posts){
  foreach ($posts as $post){
    // Process posts
});
```

2. Aunque ya lo tienes, no usaría concat y sí seleccionaría solo las tablas necesarias:

```
DB::table('pacientes')->select('id', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'dni')->chunk(100, function ($posts){
  foreach ($posts as $post){
    // Process posts
});
```

3. Usar pluck en los registros. Esta se usa, por lo general, cuando se necesita la información exacta de esas columnas:

```
$pacientes = DB::table('pacientes')->pluck('nombre','dni');
```

y luego hacer algo como esto:

```
foreach ($pacientes as $dni => $nombre){
    // $nombre es el nombre del paciente
    // $dni es el dni del paciente
}
```

Si no me equivoco, incluso pluck se puede usar con chunk y te ahorrarías aún más tiempo de consultas.

Recuerda que muchas cosas dependen de la funcionalidad de tu aplicación, además de la carga de trabajo de tu server y, sin importar cuánto las optimices, si hay alta demanda, siempre es mejor mirar servidores que se adecúen a tus necesidad; manteniendo en mente siempre la eficiencia de las consultas.

Comment: voy a probar si mejora con tus indicaciones.  Probé sin concatenarlos pero eso no lo mejoró. Probaré lo otro que comentas. y aviso. Gracias.-

Comment: Espero que sí. Aunque recuerda que mostrar más de 17000 registros de golpe, no es tarea fácil.